# Form not binding fields from Json

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have the following code in my controller:

```
Person person = Form.form(Person.class).bind(request().body().asJson()).get();
```

While there is a new instance of product that appears, **all the fields are null**.

```
@Entity
public class Person extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    public String name;

}
```

As expected, this is the json from the request:

```
{
  "name": "Richard"
}
```

I don't understand what seems to be a problem. Upon checking the website, there wasn't an example with binding from Json, does this mean this is not supported? How do I fix this? What are my alternatives?

Comment: I also have trouble with the automatic binding feature... There is an example of how you can use the JSON file in this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLrmnjPQsZc , but I know this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: @Chad Check if the `Content-Type` of the request is set to `application/json` or the method where you bind the form is annotated with `@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)`.